# How to clear the pre-post values of form fields after submit, and fill the form again with the blank fields

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

This is my website http://exmaple.com/schedule-appointment/ where I have applied a script to clear the form fields values after submit. Basically when you book the appointment for the first time and done. You again come back on the same page for another appointment then you will see that all the fields of form already filled. So I do not want this happens on the live website. I have used a script to clear the fields but it is working on firebug console but not worked on the live website. Is there anything wrong what I did earlier,
Below is my script that I have used and committed to the server.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function (){
    jQuery('.form-horizontal').each(function(){ 
        alert("hello");
        this.reset(); 
    }); 
});
</script>
```

Please help how we can clear the form fields for the second time to book an appointment.

Many thanks!

Comment: try `$('input,textarea').val('');` or `$('form').reset()`

Comment: ``$('form').find('input, textarea, select').val('')`` does this. the reset function does not work if you have customized controls. take care with the select, the first entry will be selected if you have no option with ``value=""`` defined.

Comment: You can use this link https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_form_reset

Comment: @mtizziani, Hi mate so, what code I will add to the file to clear the form fields.

Comment: @Campy see Aknosis's answer, To reset your form you can use : jQuery('.form-horizontal')[0].reset()

Comment: @Shan, hello mate it is not working.

Comment: Did you checked this code in console ?

Comment: @Shan, on console jQuery('.form-horizontal')[0].reset() it is working if I execute this with entered the script on console. But when I use this in the file and it is not working on local. And I have checked, the Script is not showing in source code also. What can i do now please help?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly caused by browser autocomplete? Try adding `autocomplete="off"` to your `form` tag.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion

Comment: hey will you have a look here saloon.ekvitech.com/schedule-appointment that I have used this script <script type="text/javascript"> jQuery(document).ready(function (){ alert("hi"); jQuery('form').reset(); }); </script> 

 
the alert box is working but form can't clear its fields. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>your page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="">
      <div>
        <input type="text" id="sngl_txt">
      </div>
      <div>
        <textarea id="mlt_txt"></textarea>
      </div>
      <div>
        <select id="selection">
          <option value="">no selection (default)</option>
          <option value="1">option 1</option>
          <!-- and so on -->
        </select>
      </div>

      <div>
        <button type="button" id="rst_btn">reset form</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </body>

<script type="text/javascript" src="link.to.your.jquery.library"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).on('ready', function(){

  // prepare with sample values
  $('form').find('#sngl_txt').val('sample text');
  $('form').find('#mlt_txt').val('Lorem ipsum ....");
  $('form').find('#selection').val(1);

  var reset = function(){
    $('form').find('input, textarea, select').val('');
  }


  $('form').find('#rst_btn').on('click', reset);

  // or
  // $('form').find('#rst_btn').on('click', function(){
  //   reset();
  // });
  // if you don't want to use the reset funtion as listener

});

</script>
</html>
```

i know in this sample a simple button type="reset works too", but i often have to work with customized controls and i had to set the value to an empty string by hand.

what you can try is `$('form').reset()` and not `$('.form-horizontal').reset()`, the effect will be the same a reset

Comment: I am currently working on local if the code is perfectly executed well then I will commit my code to the dev server. I have used this script the alert function works but script not clear the fields. <script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function (){
    alert("hi");
    jQuery('form').reset();
   
});
</script>

Comment: hey will you have a look here http://saloon.ekvitech.com/schedule-appointment/ that I have used this script <script type="text/javascript"> jQuery(document).ready(function (){ alert("hi"); jQuery('form').reset(); }); </script>

Comment: the alert box is working but form can't clear its fields. Please help.